Mean of asymptotic convergent sequences
$$
\mbox{Suppose}\ \left\{a_{n,j},\ j=1,\ldots, m_n,\ n\geq 1\right\}
$$
are sequences of real values, and for each $j$, $\left\vert a_{n,j}\right\vert \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.
$$
\mbox{Is it possible to show the mean}\
\sum_{j = 1}^{m_{n}}
{\left\vert a_{n,j}\right\vert \over m_{n}} \to 0\ ?
$$
This problem looks a bit like the Cesaro Mean Theorem but I am unsure how to connect with that.
Thanks ahead for any hints!

I think you'll need the condition that $m_n$ is bounded as $n \to \infty$. Otherwise, it's not too hard to construct a counterexample.
A hint to help you get started: Suppose you let $m_n$ be some increasing sequence (maybe $m_n = n$ for simplicity) and set $$a_{n,j} = \begin{cases} ?_n  & \text{ if } j = m_n \\ 0 & \text{ if } j < m_n\end{cases}. $$ In other words, each sequence just has a single non-zero value that might be different for each $n$.

 Can you show that for any fixed $j$, we have $|a_{n,j}| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$? Think about what happens once $n$ is large enough for $m_n > j$.


Then, can you pick values for that single non-zero element $?_n$ of each sequence so that the mean doesn't go to zero?

